# getting random error while upload photo with paperclip on my ftp server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ftp, paperclip

I used `gem "paperclip"` for upload images and `gem "paperclip-storage-ftp"` for store images on my own ftp server. It worked fine for a while, but now I am getting random errors, when I upload photos.

Sometimes this

```
Net::FTPReplyError - 150 Connecting to port 3270
```

Sometime this

```
Net::ReadTimeout - Net::ReadTimeout:
```

Sometime this

```
Paperclip::Storage::Ftp::NoServerAvailable
```

.. and sometimes this:

```
Net::FTPPermError - 500 ?
```

Model

```
class AlbumPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo, {
    # Choose the FTP storage backend
    :storage => :ftp,
    :path => "www.abcd.com/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
    :url => "ftp://abcd@domain.com@domain.com/www.abcd.com/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",

    :ftp_servers => [
      {
        :host => "domain.com",
        :user => "abcd@domain.com",
        :password => "abcd123",
        :passive => true
      }
    ],
    :styles => { :medium => "300x300^", :thumb => "100x100^" ,:large => "400x400^"},

  }  
end
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: all these errors are due to connection error. you should first check you're FTP using FileZilla client.

Comment: @LukyBoy-KU I am already checked my ftp in FileZilla client. its working fine there. this error is like if i put 5 photo for upload then i will get this error from 1/2 photo and others photos are uploaded properly. some times its working fine without error too.

Comment: try using passive FTP, [Ruby net/ftp code failing to PUT a file because of error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249853/ruby-net-ftp-code-failing-to-put-a-file-because-of-error)

Comment: I already did this passive FTP . but still facing this error.

Comment: please post you're file uploading code.

Comment: [View this link](http://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10142.aspx) may be help get you understand your problem. check for error codes.

Comment: @LukyBoy-KU see question i added my model code here.

Comment: maybe you're missing two switches in code. try this one. hope it'll help
[FTP Storage for Paperclip](https://github.com/xing/paperclip-storage-ftp)

`:ftp_connect_timeout => 5, # optional, nil by default (OS default timeout)`
& 
`:ftp_ignore_failing_connections => true, # optional, false by default`

Comment: I added both those lines in my code and start uploading 20 photos than i got new error this time Paperclip::Storage::Ftp::NoServerAvailable :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94329/discussion-between-lukyboy-ku-and-mokariya).

Comment: @KaleemUllah maybe worth posting the summary from your chat as an answer so to help 'close' this question